# How to pass arguments to function that will be executed later?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form that executes a few stored procedures, loads some data and binds textboxes, comboboxes, etc THEN AFTER the form has loaded everything a button is displayed which allows you to execute a function on click.

My question is, as my form is executing and binding data can I pass certain values I need ( Id's, which are primary keys in my database ) to this function that will be called by the button press.

I have it currently functioning using hidden labels and I am going through my code now to correct this poor design.

EDIT: I have this functioning now using public properties, is doing this too loose of a design ?

Comment: Yes you can pass values. From where you get values? from user through UI or it is passed programmatically straight to the function?

Comment: a combination of both, the user interacts with the form (Searching for a user, selecting row in listview etc) and then the form loads all the data and waits for the user to click the button which contains a function in the onclick handler that is supposed to take 3 integer  values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using public properties I was able to achieve my goal and remove the poorly designed hidden label quickfix.